# Is this enough information to prove that this figure is a parallelogram?

Tags: geometry

If one pair of opposite sides in a quadrilateral is parallel but not congruent and the other opposite pair of sides is congruent but not parallel is this enough info to prove that the figure is a parallelogram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

[image: Isoceles Trapezoid]

Consider the isosceles trapezoid.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: I see what I got wrong now. Thanks